# C# Repeaters while amending some figures

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a very large finance table, which will be repeated 4 times on a page, across many different pages. I don't like the idea of just copying the table across pages. Am I correct in thinking that I can create a repeater which repeats it? But also at the same time amend figures in the backend?

I have looked around, but wasn't to sure whether the amending of figures was possible as well as more efficient?

```
<div class="span3  finance-boxes">                
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover finance-table">
        <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="fig">Figure</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="fig">Figure</td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="#financeDetail36" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Finance Details</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create an ascx webusercontrol with the properties and make it render your HTML, replacing your figures with the values of the properties?

Comment: Hi Ihor, Could you explain further please?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from your explanation you need to repeat the same piece of HTML on many places with only difference of some values of some cells. So I suggest you create a new ASCX control.

Webusercontrol is very similar to asp.net page, but has .ascx extension and can be inserted onto page or other control. So to create it use Add -> New Item -> Web User Control in VisualStudio.

The web user control will have markup file .ascx and code-behind .ascx.cs file.
Place your html on markup file:

```
<div class="span3  finance-boxes">                
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover finance-table">
    <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="fig" runat="server" ID="cell1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="fig" runat="server" ID="cell2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#financeDetail36" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Finance Details</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now in the code-behind you can access your cells by cell1 and cell2 and you can change their inner html by cell1.InnerHtml property.
You can create public properties in your code behind file to have access to these cells from the page:

```
public string Cell1Text
{
    get
    {
        return cell1.InnterHtml;
    }
    set
    {
        cell1.InnterHtml = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can place your web user control on your page.
You can read more about this here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

Finally you will be able to access and modify your control's properties by this piece of code:
    myUserControlName.Cell1Text = "NEW TEXT";

Comment: Hi Ihor, Thank you. I have have everything understood and implemented except for the last part, about editing the Cell1 from the .cs page of the e page the control has been added too.

Comment: Would the 'myUserControlName.Cell1Text = "NEW TEXT";' go into the Page_Load of the .aspx file the control has been added too?

Comment: Well, it depends on your logic. Yes, you can assign it on Page_Load, but please read more about ASP.NET page life cycle.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx